# Windows 7 -> Windows 10 Upgrade - Error 0x80070571-0x2000c

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I'm in the process of attempting to upgrade my sister's computer to Windows 10 via the Media Creation Tool as per the instructions provided [here](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/you-can-still-upgrade-to-windows-10-for-free-heres-how/)

The tool appears to work ok, it asks a few questions, downloads the installation files, checks for updates, creates the install media then copies the files to the boot drive and restarts. The Windows 10 boot logo is shown and it says that is it checking for updates again. Screen flickers, computer restarts then a message is shown "Restoring to previous state" or something to that effect. Then I'm back in Windows7 land.

When I log back in to windows it shows an error message stating

> "0x80070571-0x2000c The installation failed in the SAFE_OS phase with
>   an error during APPLY_IMAGE operation"

Googling for that error code returned nothing of any use and neither did searching for the error message. Looking in the event viewer, I can see a seemingly related error (below) but not the error that is reported when I log in.

The error that is reported is

> "Installation failure: Windows failed to install the following update
>   with error 0x80070103: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc driver update for
>   AMD SMBus"

This is repeated several times within a 2 minute window. From what I have found online, this error message refers to Windows update trying to update to an older/incompatible version of the driver.

List of things I've tried to get the update to work:

1. Make sure Windows is up to date
2. Disabled (and then uninstalled) anti-virus (Trend Micro was installed)
3. Uninstalled AMD catalyst drivers (with AMD removal tool)
4. Remapped user folders (my docs etc) back to primary drive (c:) and unplugged secondary drive
5. Run both sfc and dism scans, neither found any issues
6. Ran chkdsk on primary drive, again no errors reported

The hardware isn't what I would consider old (March 2014) and it certainly still runs Windows 7 very well. From what I can find it meets the published minimum requirements for Windows 10.

- Gigabyte GA-F2A88XM-D3H Motherboard
- AMD A8-6500 3.5 GHz w/ Radeon HD 8570D
- Transcend SSD340 Premium SSD (64GB)
- Adata XPG Gaming Series AX3U2133XCW4G10-2X (2x 4GB)

Does anyone have any hints on getting:

- this update to work properly or
- more debugging info that might help me identify the actual root cause
  of the failure?

Comment: Starting in Windows 7, update BIOS, and all drivers including but not limited to network and video. Restart and try upgrading again. There is a Microsoft Windows update advisor program (Microsoft downloads). Get that and run it to ensure your computer will run Windows 10

Comment: Hi John, do you have a direct link to the program you are talking about? All the links I can find point to the Media Creation Tool that I have already tried. Good tip about the other drivers, I will make sure those are up to date too.

Comment: There have been so many changes that Upgrade Adviser is combined with Windows 10 install which includes the Media Creation Link. Also try this site (legitimate) as it may help as well 
https://www.intowindows.com/download-windows-10-upgrade-advisor/

Comment: Run a checkdisk on the drive before trying again.

Comment: On occasion, I found update made from USB flash drive, using media creation tool, worked where using the active HDD did not. If she is comfortable with trying another OS, Linux, e.g. Ubuntu, can be tested without installation, and if desired, actual installation takes less than half and hour. See http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/

Comment: Hello. I've rolled back your "resolved" edit. Please post your solution as an answer (you can find the edit [in the revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1530577/revisions)). This way you'll be able to accept your answer and mark the question as solved, making it more visible for others with the same issue.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - I would love to however she uses software that is only available for Windows (I did ask when I originally built this machine and every time I've had to resolve a Windows issue ... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions. I updated the chipset, network and audio drivers (all that were listed for the motherboard), same error. Updated the bios to the latest version that was listed as stable, same error.

I did some more digging and found out the [Windows 10 deployment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolve-windows-10-upgrade-errors) site has some pretty good information covering update logs and a tool for parsing them. The SetupDiag also seemed to work on my Windows 7 install. However for my particular error it didn't throw any more light on the cause (the additional errors also didn't return much when Googled).

Next I tried building USB installation media and tried upgrading with that based on the comment below that it has worked better in the past (note for others reading; seriously consider doing this first, saves downloading and rebuilding the media from scratch every time. The Media Creation Tool ignores any previous attempts to download and build the media, even if it was successful ... lesson learned, eventually). While the saved me time I also got the same error back.

Finally I bit the bullet and imaged the drive and did a clean install from the USB. Worked first time, and auto-activated (which was the reason I was trying to do an in situ upgrade in the first place).